# ngFor not working, Firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, angular5

I am attempting an example of using Angular5 with Firestore, but I cannot retrieve any data from my Firestore database. Any help would be greatly appreciated as this is a show stopper. The irony is I can insert new records into the database using the example, I just cannot retrieve anything. Thanks in advance.

app.component.html:

```
<ul *ngFor="let post of posts | async">
  <li>
    <strong>{{ post.title }}</strong>
    <br>
    {{ post.content }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { AngularFirestore } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
import { AngularFirestoreDocument } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

interface Post {
  title: string;
  content: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  postsCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Post>;
  posts: Observable<Post[]>;

  constructor (private afs: AngularFirestore) {

  }

  ngOnit() {
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts');
    this.posts = this.postsCollection.valueChanges();
  }
}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { AngularFireModule } from 'angularfire2';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from 'angularfire2/firestore';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "edited but correct",
  authDomain: "edited but correct",
  databaseURL: "edited but correct",
  projectId: "edited but correct",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "edited but correct"
};

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(firebaseConfig),
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo:

```
 ngOnit() {
```

Should be:

```
ngOnInit() {}
```

(You might even need ngAfterContentInit() if it's still not ready to load at that point in the lifecycle.)

Answer (score 0):

The error is in this line

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.postsCollection = this.afs.collection('posts');  <<HERE
    this.posts = this.postsCollection.valueChanges();
}
```

Change it to:

```
 this.postCollection = this.afs.collection< post > ('posts')
```

For reference you can read this page:

https://blog.angular.io/improved-querying-and-offline-data-with-angularfirestore-dab8e20a4a06